# Como converter um Objeto em um Array? (c#)

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public string Nome;
public int Cpf;

 public string getNome() {        
    return Nome;         
}

 public void setNome(string nome) {
    this.Nome = nome;
}

public int getCpf() {
    return Cpf;
}

public void setCpf(int cpf) {
    this.Cpf = cpf;
}
```

como posso converter em um array?

Estou querendo criar uma função para o banco de dados onde eu precise passar apenas o nome da tabela e um `Array` ou `OrderedDictionary` com o mapeamento dessa classe, para evitar ter que alterar a `query` a cada vez que eu adicionar um novo atributo a ela, eu tenho essa função em `php`e estou tentando passar para `c#` e a primeira coisa que preciso fazer é essa conversão, no `php` eu utilizo a função `implode()` com `array_keys()` para separar as `keys` nome dos campos na base de dados e os campos que seram inseridos no banco. no final tenho uma `query` assim `INSERT INTO {$table} ( {$fields} ) VALUES   ( {$values})";` que serve para inserir valores em qualquer tabela.

Comment: Qual a sua intenção? O que você gostaria que fosse adicionado ao array? `Nome` e `Cpf`? Em que ordem? Essas perguntas são apenas para mostrar que o que você está tentando fazer talvez não faça muito sentido.

Comment: Estou construindo uma aplicação e isso é para a inserção de usuários no `bd`, por enquanto essa classe possui 10 atributos  ao longo do desenvolvimento acredito que vou precisar adicionar mais informações, tenho uma função que trata a inserção desses dados com base na classe, não quero precisar reescrever as `query's` manualmente cada vez que adicionar um novo atributo a classe fazendo um mapeamento da classe utilizando um `array` ou `OrderedDictionary`.

Comment: Já que quer fazer as coisas dinamicamente, por que não faz em PHP? Em C#, apesar de ser possível, não é assim que se faz. Ou então nem crie classes em C#, faça tudo em *array*. Não que eu ache que deva fazer isto, mas se vai subverter a vantagem da linguagem, então subverta tudo. Se achar melhor, use um `Dictionary` onde você sima classes. Tem até outras formas, mas se é para fazer errado, nem vale à pena citar.

Comment: porque a aplicação é em C#, a aplicação é mobile, [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812024/how-convert-this-function-php-in-c) o pessoal me deu algumas dicas logo mais eu posto o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi, ao em vez de criar uma `Array()` como estava pensando listei utilizando um `Dictionary<string, string>`. da seguinte forma:

```
//Cria uma bindingflag que armazena as propriedades da classe.
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    BindingFlags.Instance | 
    BindingFlags.Static;

Usuario user = new Usuario();

user.setNome("Something");
user.setCPF(123456789);

var newUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Usuario).GetFields(bindingFlags))
{
      print(field.Name + " Values => " + field.GetValue(user).ToString());
      newUser.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(user).ToString());
}
```

Agora consigo construir as querys dinamicamente como faço em `php`, e não preciso mais reescrever as `querys` já que posso apenas lista-las automaticamente com a própria classe, único cuidado que o nome da variável deve ser o mesmo nome do campo na tabela na base de dados.

Answer (score 3):

Esta é uma extensão que converte as propriedades de um objeto para um dicionário de objetos tendo o nome da propriedade como chave:

```
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object obj)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
        {
            result.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

A partir daí você pode converter o dicionário para uma array, via `[dicionario].Values.ToArray();`, por exemplo.

Comment: Vou tentar isso tambem! apesar de ja ter resolvido o problema, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa utilizar um ORM como Entity Framework ou Nhibernate, pois o objetivo do ORM é exatamente realizar mapeamento entre os campos/propriedades do seu objeto e os campos/propriedades sua tabela no base de dados.

O próprio ORM cria e executa o comando de inserção, atualização, etc. sendo desnecessário que você realize esse trabalho manualmente.

---

Referências úteis:

[Site NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/)
[Código fonte Entity Framework 6 (e anteriores)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6)
[Código fonte Entity Framework 7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework)

Comment: eu tenho uma função em php que realiza esse procedimento com apenas 7 linhas de código, usar um framework para realizar esse processo?! estou procurando funções similares a utilizada no php para transcreve-lo em c#. mais obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Sim, quando puder leia as referências, pois os benefícios desses ORMs vão muito além do que você imagina. Se fosse vantajoso fazer utilizando uma função como você imagina, todos nós já estaríamos utilizando essa tal função e não utilizamos ORM.

Comment: eu entendo, mais no meu caso usar um framework seria como matar uma mosca com um canhão.